# Open/Libre/Free source scientific computing software for magnetism

Tags: scientific-computing

I am searching for scientfic computing software for the field of magnetism. Are there any indexes on the web which enlist softwares pertaining to magnetism in particular and/or scientific computing software by fields in general? I remember one such index as a repository on GitHub, however I am unable to retrieve it because, not only  I forgot bookmarking it but also probably due to [GitHub's poor search capability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Preston-Werner#GitHub)

Comment: 1. *computing software for the field of magnetism* is too vague. Please [be more specific](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). 2. Asking for "indexes on the web" is off-topic 3. Your complaint about Github search is irrelevant to the question. Please [edit] your question

Comment: What type of problems are you looking to solve? The answer to this question would totally determine the potential set of answers.